# Drawing a circle in Swift (MacOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, draw, geometry

I've found this code for drawing the line for MacOS app.

```
 class Drawing: NSView {
        override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
            super.draw(dirtyRect)

            let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext;

            context!.beginPath()
            context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
            context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
            context!.setStrokeColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            context!.setLineWidth(1.0)
            context!.strokePath()
        }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let dr = Drawing(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(dr)
}
```

How to change this code for circle? It's difficult for me to solve this problem. Help me, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The circle equivalent is

```
class Drawing: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext
        context.saveGState()
        context.setFillColor(NSColor.red.cgColor)
        context.fillEllipse(in: dirtyRect)
        context.restoreGState()
    }   
}
```

or the classic `NSBezierPath` way

```
class Drawing: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        let fillColor = NSColor.red
        let path = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: dirtyRect)
        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the side of the circle, you can also do this:

```
class YourParentView: NSView {

    // Create it as a view of its own
    let circleView = NSView()
    circleView.wantsLayer = true

    circleView.layer?.cornerRadius = 7 
    //depending on the size, adjust this
    //and that's it. Now it's a circle.

    //Then just addict the style
    circleView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    circleView.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.white.cgColor

    //Be sure to add it to the parent view
    self.view.addSubview(circleView)
}
```